# How to show the cumulative count from the previous month vs current month in each site

Tags: tableau-api

Please help me to solve this issues.

This is my table:

[image]

i have created the visualization month wise cumulative count of actual and projected count it working fine.

[image]

Here i have the issue if i click the October month it will show the correct result 101 - 4, 102 - 1, 103 - 3, 104 - 0. if i click the November month it will show 101 - 6, 102 - 0, 103 - 0, 104 - 0 but i need the result is 101 - 10, 102 - 1, 103 - 3, 104 - 0. (101 - 10 is the Oct and Nov month sum).

Bar chart is the actual count (green), Gantt bar is the projected count(Orange).

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking,did you try filtering the months?

Comment: yes i filtering the month.

Comment: is it possible to share via tableau public , might help solve this. Just images wont help getting the problem .

Comment: I have requested question in tableau forums. Please refer the link - "community.tableau.com/"; please search the question  "How to find the difference from the previous Month in each site" there its self attached the workbook.